How to append a pattern to each list member from back quote output?
For example if I do git diff --name-only under a git local directory, the command returns the list of files seen from the git root directory like this.
ab21/ab21_universe.sv
ab21cv/apzeus/aarch64/cvp_earth/hello_world/Makefile.inc
ab21cv/apzeus/aarch64/shared/stackheap.s
ab21cv/apzeus/cvp_category/cvp_earth/hello_world/hello_world.c
ab21cv/apzeus/cvp_category/shared/ab21x_zeus_uart.h

But since I am now in simab21/sim_rtl directory from the git root position, to do something to those files, I have to append ../.. to each members of the output above. For example for the question, if I want to do cat for those files, how should I do it?  I can do things like
for i in `git diff --name-only`
do
cat ../../$i
done

But I cannot do ls -ltrd git diff --name-only (characters in the shade is inside back quotes) because the git diff --name-only outputs files lists seen from git root directory. Hope my explanation comes through. How can I do that?

You can use sed to modify the file names:
ls -ltrd $(git diff --name-only | sed 's=^=../../=')

(Note that I used $(...) instead of back quotes, as they nest cleanly).
This only works if the file names don't contain spaces.

Yeah, using $(...) is the thing I was looking for. (I've seen it before but I forgot and it's very useful.). Thanks!

Since "the command returns the list of files seen from the git root directory" wouldn't it make more sense to put your git root directory in front of each path instead of ../.. as the latter will break if you run it from any other directory? e.g. using any awk:
git diff --name-only | awk -v g=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) '{print g "/" $0}'

